# How to convert date/time from GMT to local timezone

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I'm getting a date time string from a JSON response that looks like this:

`2019-07-18 13:39:05`

This time is GMT.  How can I convert this to locale time zone, in my case Eastern with day light savings.

```
func convertDateFormat(date:String) -> String {

    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatterPrint.timeStyle = .short

    let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: date)

    return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date!)

}
```

In the code above the result should be `July 18, 2019 at 9:39 AM`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is a fixed-format date string in GMT, therefore `dateFormatterGet` must have

- the locale set to "en_US_POSIX" (otherwise it can default to the user's locale settings, compare [What is the best way to deal with the NSDateFormatter locale "feechur"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feechur)), and
- the time zone set to GMT (otherwise it defaults to the user's time zone):

Example:

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatterGet.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Everything else should be OK: you don't set a time zone for `dateFormatterPrint` so that the user's time zone is used.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.