# Why does my NSDateFormatter sometimes return an a.m. or p.m. with yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4

Sometimes my code is returning an a.m. or p.m. but not always. Most of the time it just returns what I expect, which is something like: 20110815170852164

But other times it's returning: 20100412010241 a.m.450

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

What could be causing this? Specific date/time country settings on users iPhones? I have this out to thousands of people, and most aren't returning the a.m. (which is expected) but others are. WHY?

Comment: help me to solve this problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162835/how-to-use-nsdateformatter-to-venezuela

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem you are describing is a known bug. [Check out some discussion on the problem on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143075/nsdateformatter-am-i-doing-something-wrong-or-is-this-a-bug), and you can find some possible work-arounds there.

Here's an excerpt of huyz's explaination of the bug:

> The problem comes from NSDateFormatter somehow “getting stuck” in the 12 or 24-hour time mode that the user has manually selected. So if a French user manually selects 12-hour mode, and the application requested NSDateFormatter to output time with the 24-hour format “HHmm”, it would actually receive time in a 12-hour format, e.g. “01:00 PM”, as if the application had instead requested “hhmm aa”. The reverse would happen if a US user manually selected 24-hour mode: outputting time with the 12-hour format “hhmm aa” would actually get you time in the 24-hour format instead, e.g. “17:00″.

Comment: Well, Apple has declared that it isn't a "bug", it's a "feature" (more properly spelled "feechure" in this context).

Answer (score 4):

Right.  The solution is to explicitly set the locale of the date formatter, ideally to en_US_POSIX.  See the final answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformater-locale-feature) question.

Answer (score 3):

I was working on a data-share function of a project which was highly depending on the values/results entered in advance when I bumped into the same problem. I implemented a nasty little workaround for saving the right datetime in 24h format to the database.

**The solution is very simple**

First, I get the local date from the device:

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
```

Second step is to create a `NSDateFormatter` with US locale regardless of system's locale to make sure that "PM" is going to be "PM":

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
```

Then, I get the date (year, month, day) into a string:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *date = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
```

For the next part, I get the hours, minutes and seconds:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh"];
NSString *hours = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"mm"];
NSString *minutes = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];
NSString *seconds = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
```

Next, I get the part of the day:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"a"];
NSString *partOfDay = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
```

Then comes the logic: if the part of the day is PM but the hours are less then 12, we just have to correct that. In code:

```
if([partOfDay isEqualToString:@"PM"] && [hours intValue] < 12) {
    hours = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", ([hours intValue] + 12)];
}
```

After this modification, we are ready to put the string together in order to have a datetime ready to be saved into SQL:

```
NSString *sqlDateTime = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@:%@", date, hours, minutes, seconds];
```

That's all there is to it. And from now we can only hope that Apple is going to fix this bug to make it work as it should be.

I hope this helps.

Comment: And what if the locale is different than en_US, and "PM" is not "PM"?

Comment: AM and PM is coming from the Latin 'ante meridiem' and 'post meridiem' phrases meaning before/after midday. They are not used in any other languages but English. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock)
I tried to find equivalents, but did not succeed, so I assume that your scenario - although it's very valid - would never happen.

Comment: It happens. The AM/PM are localized. I can attest for Hebrew equivalent.

Comment: @LeoNatan, actually, you are right, sorry for only scratching the surface... :) It happens, but you can still ask the `NSDateFormatter` to use the en_US format with `[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]` and this way you can make sure that "PM" is going to be "PM", regardless of the actual system's locale.

Comment: @LeoNatan - thanks for bringing it to my attention and throughout help everybody to use a better source for their purpose. I have modified the code above with the latest improvement. Thank you!

Comment: But why would you ask for an en_US locale, when the user is not using an English locale, and may, indeed, not even know English? Some people are not familiar with "AM" and "PM". Yes, there are such people. :)

Comment: I completely agree Leo! However, my sample code explains a scenario I ran into, where I needed to store the _correct_ time in the database in 24h format (`@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`) for comparison at a later time, all without the intention of displaying the actual data but rather to do the calculations in the background.