# NSDateFormatter doesn't work on actual equipment

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I tried to use `NSDateFormatter` like following.
On simulator, it works fine. -> 2015-06-01
But, on actual equipment, it does't work. it'll be nil.

```
let d = "Wed Jul 01 04:48:51 +0000 2015"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
if let date = formatter.dateFromString(d) {
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    self.dateLabel?.text = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

Is this iPhone's problem?

Comment: @martin-r that was right! thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be an issue with locale and 12/24-hour time handling. 
Try forcing formatter's locale to be consistent for the date you are receiving.

```
let d = "Wed Jul 01 04:48:51 +0000 2015"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
if let date = formatter.dateFromString(d) {
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    self.dateLabel?.text = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

Check these [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143075/nsdateformatter-am-i-doing-something-wrong-or-is-this-a-bug) for more info.